# Laravel 5.6 Multi-relation eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have the following database structure:

- sport
- camera
- sport_has_camera

With a relation in `sport_has_camera`.

So the table `sport_has_camera` holds the ID from both the sport and the camera.

Now I have a model called `Sport.php` and `Camera.php`. I want to be able to do: `Sport::where('name' , $sport_name)->firstOrFail()->cameras` what would return all the camera's of that sport (linked in the database. Now I have this in `Sport.php`:

```
public function cameras()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Camera');
    }
```

But that doesn't do what I want, how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `belongsToMany`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Camera::class, 'sport_has_camera', 'sport_id', 'camera_id');
```

Comment: Oh gash, I looked over that the whole time in the docs... Thank you so much!